# How can I disable filters on bubbleChart using .removeFilterHandler?

Tags: dc.js

I need to suppress the filtering that happens when a user clicks on a circle in a bubbleChart but keep the class assignment of 'selected' and 'deselected' if possible. If not possible, I'd like to replace the default click behaviour with my own script.

According to the API docs, I can use .removeFilterHandler or .resetFilterHandler on a bubbleChart, since the chart type relies upon baseMixin.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+removeFilterHandler

But it's not working. When I click on a circle in the bubbleChart, a histogram in the same dashboard filters. I would expect this to stop. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm using DC.js v2.0.2.  Thanks

```
  var rfh = bubbleChart.resetFilterHandler();

  bubbleChart.width(738)
          .height(315)
          .margins({left:40,right:30,top:15,bottom:30})
          .dimension(idDimBubble)
          .group(idGrpBubble)
          .clipPadding(10)
          .renderLabel(false)
          .keyAccessor(function (p) { return p.value[selectArrays[0][1]] / p.value.name.length; })
          .valueAccessor(function (p) { return p.value[selectArrays[0][0]] / p.value.name.length; })
          .radiusValueAccessor(function (p) { return p.value['revenue']+1; })
          .title(function(d){
            var tempIndex = filters[0].indexOf(window.gran);
            var tempString = filters[1][tempIndex]+': ' + d.value.what;
            var str = '';
            if (window.gran!='company') {
              str = 'Avg ';
            }
            tempString += '\n'+str+selectArrays[1][0]+': '+d3.format('.3s')(Math.round(d.value[selectArrays[0][0]] / d.value.name.length));
            tempString += '\n'+str+selectArrays[1][1]+': '+d3.format('.3s')(Math.round(d.value[selectArrays[0][1]] / d.value.name.length));

            return tempString;
          })
          .minRadius(3)
          .maxBubbleRelativeSize(0.005)
          .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, selectArrays[3][1]]))
          .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, selectArrays[3][0]]))
          .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 5000]))
          .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
          .renderVerticalGridLines(true)
          .removeFilterHandler(function (filters, filter) {
              console.log(filters);//doesn't output anything
              for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                  if (filters[i] <= filter && filters[i] >= filter) {
                      filters.splice(i, 1);
                      break;
                  }
              }
              return filters;
          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of a few functions are ambiguous here.

The `removeFilterHandler` does not itself remove filters; it is called when a user action causes a filter to be removed. It just changes the list before it's applied.

What you want to do is keep the way filters are added and removed but change (disable) the way they are applied to the dimension.

This is what the `filterHandler` is for. [Similar name, different functionality.](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler) Maybe it should be called the `applyFiltersHandler`. Or something.

You can implement it as a pass-through:

```
chart.filterHandler(function (dimension, filters) {
    return filters;
});
```

It preserves the list of filters, but doesn't apply them to the dimension this way.

Comment: Thanks! This worked: .filterHandler(function(dimension,filters){ dimension.filter(null); return filters; });